# Delete list item in VBA

Tags: vba

Want to delete list item when I click on it

Code is:

```
Private Sub ListBox2_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(i) Then
        ListBox2.RemoveItem (i)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Loop backwards, once you delete an item counting forward breaks. `For i = ListBox.ListCount to 1 step -1`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.